# how to show this video on splash full screen and in portrait mode

Tags: android

https://www.freeloops.tv/time-lapse-videos-1/mountains-snow-time-lapse-1/

```
    myvideo =(VideoView )findViewById(R.id.myvideo);
    myvideo.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.loopxx);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) myvideo.getLayoutParams();
    params.width =  metrics.widthPixels;
    params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
    params.leftMargin = 0;
    myvideo.setLayoutParams(params);
    myvideo.start();
    myvideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the exact problem u getting?

Comment: @Dilip hi, i need to see the video in fullscreen mode using this method i cant see video in full screen mode.

Comment: it will be visible in full screen just put videoview inside Relativelayout and set android:layoutAlignParentBottom as well as top,left and right true

Comment: @Dilip  worked men!!! awsm

Comment: I have posted answer as well, you can accept it. It will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use RelativeLayout and set layoutAlignParentBottom as well as top,left and right true to show video in full screen.

```
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/vv"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </VideoView>
     </RelativeLayout>
```